# DAG backfilling for many dates

Tags: airflow

I have a DAG that i need to backfill for many dates. Due to resources i think the best option is to create a list of dates between a start and end date and in a for loop, run the task.
Should i have a function that returns all the dates (after formatting) to a variable and run the DAG task in a for loop or should the list of dates be part of a function that runs as a task and then somehow uses Xcom to send the list of dates? How can this be assigned to a variable with xcom pull but not requiring a task?

Answer (score 0):

Let me focus on the first part of the question, and not on the way you are suggesting to solve it:

> I have a DAG that I need to backfill for many dates.

But you don't want to run all the dates at the same time because of limited resources!

I would look into utilizing the [max_active_runs_per_dag](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#max-active-runs-per-dag) configuration variable that airflow provides out of the box. You don't need to create any additional logic.

This way you can limit the backfill process to a certain dag runs in parallel. For example if I want to only have 2 dag runs at a time:

```
export AIRFLOW__CORE__MAX_ACTIVE_RUNS_PER_DAG=2; airflow backfill -s {start_date} -e {end_date} --reset-dagruns {dag_id}
```

Run with --dry-run if you want to get a feel of what's happening before you execute the actual backfill command.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe the phrasing was not very accurate. The regular DAG creates an EMR cluster on which the task runs. I would prefer running 1 task for each date but on the same cluster.

Comment: I think you can accomplish what you want in two commands. First one, runs only the first task from the dag run scheduled at {start_date} of your backfill `airflow tasks run -f -A dag_id task_id run_id`, then when that finishes you can run the backfill command similar to my answer in addition to this flag `-t task_id_2` to only backfill the 2nd tasks of your dag runs. If there is one more task that stops the cluster, you can call it when backfill finishes, similar to the first command.

Answer (score 0):

**1) You don't want your DAG to exhaust limited resources :**

Limit your dag with max_active_runs or max_active_tasks

```
DAG(
    "MyDAG",
    start_date=datetime(2021, 1, 1),
    schedule_interval="@hourly",
    catchup=False,
    tags=["benchmark"],
    max_active_runs=1,
    max_active_tasks=1
)
```

Limit your resource utilisation using pools

```
MyOperator(
 task_id="MyTask",
 ...
 pool="MyPool"
)
```

In admin/pool set the capacity to 1 or more

**2) You wan't to programatically control your DAG :**

Create a second DAG.
In this new DAG add a `TriggerDagRunOperator`
When using the TriggerDagRunOperator use the `conf` argument to carry information to your main DAG (in your case, you would carry dates)